# Confidence interval in {ggplot} geom_smooth regression plot appears only below regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, confidence-interval, smoothing

I've searched everywhere on the internet but I cannot find an answer to my problem. I have plotted a smooth regression line with confidence intervals with ggplot, but the confidence area is not displayed as a band around the regression line, but only below the line.
Is this a graphing error or am I missing the right mathematics as an explanation?

I've used the following code:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

fig <-
  df %>%
  mutate(
    Legend = case_when(
      ind == "currentLifetimeRisk" ~ "Lifetime risk",
      ind == "currentTenYearRisk" ~ "Ten year risk"
    )
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age_measurements,
             y = values,
             fill=Legend)) +
  geom_smooth(
    aes(ymin = 0,
        ymax = ..y..,),
    alpha = 0.8,
    formula = y ~ s(x, k = 9, bs="cs"),
    color= "black", # kleur van de lijn
    stat = "smooth",
    method = "gam",
    se = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 25),
                     limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(30, max(fig2_long$age_measurements), 10), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(
    axis.text =element_text(family = "sans", size=18,colour = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(size=18),
    axis.line.x = element_line(size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour="black"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour="black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "lightgrey"),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Age at risk estimation",
    y = "Risk of recurrent events (%)",
  )
```

fig [image: Figure I got with 95% CI only below regression line]

I expected to see the 95% conf interval as a band around the regression line, not only below. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Tinka, could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `aes(ymax=..y..)` is forcing the top of the confidence interval to be equal to the fitted y value of the regression line calculated by `geom_smooth`. If you remove `aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ..y..)`, the correct confidence intervals will be plotted.

`..y..`, `..ymax..`, and `..ymin..` are values calculated internally by `geom_smooth` in order to plot the regression line and confidence intervals. Setting `ymax=..y..` forces `geom_smooth` to use `..y..` (the fitted y value of the regression) rather than `..ymax..` (the calculated top of the 95% confidence interval) as the top of the 95% confidence interval in the plot, resulting in the issue you're seeing. (I'm actually not sure why `ymin=0` isn't forcing the bottom of the 95% confidence interval to be zero.)

Removing the `aes` mappings (which aren't needed for `geom_smooth`) results in the expected plotting of the confidence intervals. The example below reproduces the issue you're seeing:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 = mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp, fill=factor(vs))) +
  geom_smooth(
    aes(ymin=0, ymax = ..y..,),
    alpha = 0.8,
    formula = y ~ s(x, k=9, bs="cs"),
    color= "black", # kleur van de lijn
    stat = "smooth",
    method = "gam",
    se = TRUE
  ) 

p2 = mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp, fill=factor(vs))) +
  geom_smooth(
    alpha = 0.8,
    formula = y ~ s(x, k=9, bs="cs"),
    color= "black", # kleur van de lijn
    stat = "smooth",
    method = "gam",
    se = TRUE
  ) 

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>